# Destructing an object and using it - React prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component that receives a prop, 2 values should be destructed from the prop and the prop itself should be passed further, I tried the following but am receiving a `Line 23:3:  Duplicate key 'countryData'  no-dupe-keys` warning.

```
const IndividualCountryContainer = ({
  countryData: {
    name: { common },
    flags: { png },
  },
  countryData
}) => (
  <div className='country'>
    <img className='country-flag' src={png} alt={`${common}'s flag`} />
    <IndividualCountryData countryData={countryData} />
  </div>
);
```

So, how do I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Destructure your prop inside your function definition, like:

```
const IndividualCountryContainer = ({ countryData }) => {
  const {
    name: { common },
    flags: { png },
  } = countryData;

  return (
    <div className="country">
      <img className="country-flag" src={png} alt={`${common}'s flag`} />
      <IndividualCountryData countryData={countryData} />
    </div>
  );
};
```